# Got error when upgrade CentOS

Tags: svn, centos

Im upgrading my server, but there's error occurred 
Here the error report

```
Transaction Check Error:
  package subversion-1.6.15-0.1.el5.rfx.x86_64 (which is newer than subversion-1.6.11-7.el5_6.4.i386) is already installed
  file /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/psvn.el from install of subversion-1.6.11-7.el5_6.4.i386 conflicts with file from package subversion-1.6.15-0.1.el5.rfx.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/subversion.mo from install of subversion-1.6.11-7.el5_6.4.i386 conflicts with file from package subversion-1.6.15-0.1.el5.rfx.x86_64
  file /usr/share/xemacs/site-packages/lisp/psvn.el from install of subversion-1.6.11-7.el5_6.4.i386 conflicts with file from package subversion-1.6.15-0.1.el5.rfx.x86_64
```

how to solve that :(

Comment: This should probably be moved to [unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or somewhere else.